# How can implement audience targeting for a text on a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, target-audience

I wanted to know if there is a way I can do audience targeting for text on a SharePoint online site. I do not have access to SharePoint designer or PowerApps.

The text is as follows:

```
Protocol for Emailing Tickets
When emailing the PMO, please use the following Subject Line formatting:

If the PMO is being asked to examine an issue, the following email subject line language should be used:
            [ACTION REQUIRED] PMO Examination Needed
If the PMO is being asked to provide a detailed response, the following subject line language should be used:
            [RESPONSE REQUIRED] PMO Response Needed
If the PMO is being asked to provide approval, the following subject line language should be used:
            [APPROVAL REQUIRED] PMO Approval Needed
```

It doesn't matter how it's displayed (news post, list, etc), as long as this text appears on the SharePoint landing page for select users. All other users would not be able to see the text.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could create a News web part and enable audience targeting on it.

You can refer this article to have a try:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165

Good luck,

Terence

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use audience targeting on "Text" web part in SharePoint online site.

Audience targeting can be enabled for below web parts. You can use anyone of it:

1. News web part
2. Highlighted content web part
3. [Quick links web part](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)
4. Events web part

**Note**: Audience targeting supports only Azure Active Directory groups (including security groups, Microsoft 365 groups, and AAD dynamic groups) (and not SharePoint groups).

**Documentation**: [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)